# A site for random useful javascript snippets for web development?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm going through a pretty amazing ruby on rails course. Just a second ago I learned about flash hashes that show a message after some action has been performed.

Obviously, you can apply styling to it and what have you, but I wonder if there are ready-to-go javascript snippets out there that, in the case of flash hashes, would slide in for a second, and then disappear? (much like the stackoverflow message bar that appears up top)

I don't know if learning rudimentary javascript is something I'd want to do right now (maybe later, I need to stick with one thing) so I was wondering if there was some resource that is known for ready to go scripts like that?

Merci :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for but the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) libraries provide a fair number of animation effects that you might find useful.

- [jQuery UI `effect()` demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) - you can also view the source to see how it's being done.
- [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) - in particular, you might be interested in [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/). Again, you can also view the source to see how to use these functions.

Comment: Yeah, see, I think rails has that sort of thing included and I realized it only now that you've mentioned it. jQuery is a completely different thing than AJAX though, right?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library - it does nothing that you wouldn't be able to do with 'just' JavaScript yourself - it just makes it a lot easier since the library takes care of cross-browser compatibility, expressive syntax etc. Ajax refers to web techniques where data is loaded without having to refresh the page. So when you click a link, requests can be made 'in the background' rather than being old-school links to other resources. Your entire site could be just one web-page that dynamically loads data using ajax.

Comment: Ajax (almost necessarily) includes the use of JavaScript but Ajax is not JS and JS is more than just ajax. The [Wikipedia page for ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) might help explain better than I can.